# trying to implement a rudimentary progress indicator

Tags: c++, progress-bar

i have a template class i am using to load in data from a text file, and i was wanting to implement a rudimentary progress indicator because the datasets are pretty big..

here is the code:

```
template <class T>
    void loadCustomers(const char* fileName, T& container)
    {
        ifstream fin(fileName, ios_base::in);
        int line = 0;
        char c;
        cout << "Loading " << fileName << ": ";
        while (fin)
        {
            line++;
            if (line % (custSize/10) == 0)
                cout << " *";

            Customer *temp;

            try
            {
                c = fin.peek(); 
                if (c == ios::traits_type::eof())
                    break;
                else if (c == 'C')
                    temp = new Customer();
                else
                    throw boost::bad_lexical_cast();

                fin >> *temp;
                container.addElementByDate(temp);
            }
            catch(boost::bad_lexical_cast&)
            {
                cerr << "Bad data found at line " << line 
                    << " in file "<< fileName << endl;
            }
        }

        fin.close();
        cout << endl;
    }
```

the code works fine to load the files in, so that isnt a problem (many thanks to the helpful people on this forum!)

basically i just want it to print a new " *" to the screen whenever it gets to another 10% of loading, but when i run it, it loads through the whole program without even printing "Loading customers.txt: " to cout..

basically i run the program, it loads for about 30 seconds and then all at once prints:

```
Loading customers.txt  * * * * * * * * * *
```

does anyone have any idea what might be going on to make this happen? and what i can do to force it to print to the screen when it is supposed to?

Answer (score 0):

You should flush the stream to "force" it to display the data after each progress advance:

```
cout.flush();
```